# You cannot supply a time with the date when running a query using date precision

Tags: c#, sql, tfs

I am working on tfs workitem. I am trying to fetch the workitem collection using query, i am getting the following error. Any help me please?

[System.ChangedDate] > '4/19/06 1:00 PM' the following error is returned "You cannot supply a time with the date when running a query using date precision. The error is caused by «[System.ChangedDate] > '4/19/06 1:00 PM'»." yet this Field is of DateTime precision. Any suggestions or answers to why this is occuring?

```
var myquery= " SELECT [System.Id]" +
        " FROM WorkItems " +
    " WHERE " +
    " [System.TeamProject] = '" + ivSettings.Project + "'" + 
        " AND [System.ChangedDate] = '" + ivSettings.LastSyncGen + "'" + " " +
    " ORDER BY [System.Id]"

                 , null,false);
    Query qry = new Query(myworkitemstore, myquery, mycontext, false);

    ICancelableAsyncResult car = qry.BeginQuery();
      WorkItemCollection items = qry.EndQuery(car);
```

The above is my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the following line is what you're using:

```
    Query qry = new Query(myworkitemstore, myquery, mycontext, false);
```

You shouldn't get this error when the last parameter is set to false. The error should only occur when you set that parameter to true or don't supply it at all. The default is true.

Reference:
http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/01/specifying-date-and-time-in-wiql.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - have you tried doing this query in the TFS API

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8088/tfs")); 
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated(); 
    var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    var query = string.Format(@"     Select [Id], [Work Item Type], [Title], [State], [System.ChangedDate] From WorkItems", title);
    List<WorkItem> workItems = workItemStore.Query(query)
```

And then doing a LINQ query on the System.Changed Date...

I haven't tried it but that could work?

Comment: No that didnt work, I have set the field to false, still i have the same issue, thats why i have re posted here

Comment: Just posted a new suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while trying to query for the latest updates and worked around it by doing the following

```
// defined elsewhere
private DateTime lastUpdated;


string consult = "select * from WorkItem where [Created Date] > ' "  + lastUpdated.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + 
                    "' AND [Work Item Type] = 'Test Case'";

IEnumerable<ITestCase> tcc = testManagementTeamProject.TestCases.Query(consult).Where(tp => tp.DateCreated > lastUpdated);
```

I did something very similar for retrieving test results

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and Ravianth's solution worked for me. The problem might be with the date format. In my case converting the date to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format worked.